# AppleScript, InDesign, and colour swatches

Tags: colors, applescript, adobe-indesign

I've hit a bit of a roadblock when it comes to creating swatches based on entries in a text file. I can get the file to be read okay, but when it comes to actually creating the swatch (or editing an existing one) it fails.

Assuming the value of c1 is "0,100,100,5", this is editing the existing one:

```
set swatch ("CLIENT1") to c1
```

And this is creating a new one:

```
make new color with properties {model:process, space:CMYK, color value:{c1}, name:"CLIENT1"}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the variable **c1** is a string, not a list.

You need a list wich contains **integer**.

Here is a solution :

```
set c1 to "0,100,100,5"
set c1 to run script "{" & c1 & "}"
```

-- Edit :

Here's how to change the color of an existing swatch

```
tell active document
    set color value of swatch "CLIENT1" to c1 -- change one property

    -- or change properties 
    set properties of swatch "CLIENT1" to {model:process, space:CMYK, color value:c1}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you'd have any idea why it'd return an error with this code: `set color of swatch "CLIENT1" to c1`?

The error is this: error "Adobe InDesign CS5.5 got an error: Can’t set color of swatch \"CLIENT1\" of document id 12 to {0, 100, 100, 5}." number -10006 from color of swatch "CLIENT1" of document id 12